# Why can't i turn on inverse kinematics with rigify

Tags: rigging, rigify, inverse-kinematics

I got a rigged 3d model and for some reason when I try to turn on inverse kinematics an error pops up saying

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File  "D:\Stan\CG-assets\repromancer_slender_man_game_res\repromancer_slender_man_rigged.blend_ui.py", line 433, in execute AttributeError."Context" object has no attribute "user_preferences"

location: <unknown location>:-1"
```

I hope I'm not pressing the wrong button (that would be stupid)

[image: wrong button]

Comment: try making your own rig

Comment: If you share you file I'd like to take a look. Just the metarig will do, no character needed.

Comment: [rig](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1Sk6MCdehUS63BZBZ8fF75njOFXRs9b8Z?usp=sharing) tell me if you need anything else